# asm.js type error: arguments to a comparison must both be signed, unsigned or doubles

Tags: javascript, asm.js

I'm just learning the basics of asmjs, but I've got an error. I have no idea what did I wrong.

```
TypeError: asm.js type error: arguments to a comparison must both be signed, unsigned or doubles; int and int are given
```

code:

```
window.onload = (function(stdlib, foreign) {
    "use asm";

    var log = foreign.log;

    function main() {
        var a=0, b=0;

        a=10;
        b=20;

        if(a<b) {
            log(0.0);
        } else {
            log(1.0);
        }

        return;
    }

    return {main:main};
}(window, {log:console.log})).main;
```

Comment: Why are you coding asm.js by hand?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of different parts of the [specification](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/) at play here. Let's work our way backwards from the error.

The error states: `arguments to a comparison must both be signed, unsigned or doubles; int and int are given`. Thus, the problem is with the following line of code:

```
    ...
    if(a < b) { // <- Here
        log(0.0);
    } else {
        log(1.0);
    }
    ...
```

If we look up the [type semantics of the operator `<`](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#binary-operators), we get the following table:

```
(signed, signed) → int ∧
(unsigned, unsigned) → int ∧
(double, double) → int
```

This clearly reflects the wording of the error message; the `<` operator is only valid for comparisons between signed, unsigned, or double types. "But *why*?", you ask?

The [description of the `int` type](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#int) may give us a hint. Here's an excerpt:

> The int type is the type of 32-bit integers **where the signedness is
>   not known**. In asm.js, the type of a variable never has a known
>   signedness. [...] However, **this representation creates an
>   overlap between signed and unsigned numbers that causes an ambiguity
>   in determining which JavaScript number they represent**. For example,
>   the bit pattern 0xffffffff could represent 4294967295 or -1, depending
>   on the signedness. For this reason, values of the int type are
>   disallowed from escaping into external (non-asm.js) JavaScript code.

Thus, taking the comparison operation in isolation, ASM.js would have no way of knowing which of the two `int` values is less than the other, because it would not know the signedness of the integers.

So, why are the variables being resolved as type `int`?

Since you're declaring the variables inside of the function itself, we must refer to [the following part of the spec](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#variable-type-annotations):

> The types of variable declarations are determined by their
>   initializer. A variable initializer may be a floating-point literal,
>   which is any *numeric literal with the character .* in their source, and
>   has type **double**. Alternatively, an initializer may be an *integer
>   literal in the range [-231, 232)*, which has type **int**.

There we go. Since you're initializing the variables as `var a=0, b=0;`, that corresponds to the latter part of the spec, thus resolving to a type of `int`.

---

So **how do we fix this**? Well, we need a type cast to something that the `<` operator supports. The `|` operator can take two `intish` expressions, and return a `signed`, so that will suffice.

```
    if ((a|0) < (b|0)) {
        log(0.0);
    } else {
    ...
```

**Note:** [The type diagram](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/subtypes.png), together with the [operator type rules](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#operators) are very useful when trying to debug type issues like this.

Comment: thank you, but isn't it too slow, to coerce the a, and b variables every time?

Comment: @donkaka: I don't think so - the coercion is done so that the ASM.js compiler can figure our how to treat the data within the `int` types. Without it, it can't know if the `int`s are signed or unsigned. Once it has been compiled into machine code, however, there's no "coercion" that occurs anymore, the correct operations have already been compiled and can run at full speed.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message explains, *arguments to a comparison must both be signed, unsigned or doubles*; this is required by the [RelationalExpression validation](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#relationalexpression) and the [operator table](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#binary-operators).

However, your `a` and `b` variables are assigned [NumericLiterals](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#numericliteral) that only validate as [`fixnum`](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#fixnum-0), an `int` type where the compiler does not know whether they are signed or not.

So you need to tell it with an explicit expression to validate their type that they are either unsigned

```
if ( a>>>0 < b>>>0 )
```

or signed

```
if ( a|0 < b|0 ) // any of &, ^, <<, >> or ~~ should work
```

Comment: I'm not sure (and cannot test) whether `a = 10|0; b = 20|0;` would work as well

Comment: I don't think it would. Since the variables are declared as `var a = 0;`, they have type T of `int`. The assignment operator has types: `lhs: T, rhs: sigma -> T`, so even though the expressions `10|0` and `20|0` evaluate as type `signed`, the variables will remain of type `int` since `signed` is a subtype of `int`, and the comparison operation will still fail later on. (And yes, I tested it, and it fails, saying that the variables are `int`s)

Comment: @voithos: Yeah, I had suspected that. It seemed odd at first that you can change the type of an `int` variable by using it differently, but it indeed is the way it works.

Comment: Not when working with simple int variables: "asm.js type error: index expression isn't shifted; must be an Int8/Uint8 access"